# Sending messages from two different applications (different JVMs) to same IBM MQ queue (not topic)

Tags: java, ibm-mq

Is it possible to send messages from two different applications (different JVM) to same IBM MQ queue (not topic) ?

Comment: As far as I know you can send messages to an IBM MQ queue from an arbitrary number of applications running on an arbitrary number of computers. When using Java you just need to install "WebSphere MQ classes for Java" from the IBM website.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible for two or more different applications to put to the same queue.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, It is possible. To make sure any number of instances of an application or any number of applications to open the queue, we need to have the definition of the queue like below.

```
    dis q(SAMPLE) SHARE DEFSOPT 
    6 : dis q(SAMPLE) SHARE DEFSOPT 
   AMQ8409: Display Queue details. 

   QUEUE(SAMPLE) TYPE(QLOCAL) 
   DEFSOPT(SHARED) SHARE
```

SHARE - will allow any number of instances of an application to access the queue at a time.
DEFSOPT(SHARED) - Any number of applications can access the queue at a time.